# Any other case where the male and female citizen is the same?

Tags: gender, grammaticality

I recently stumbled upon this:

'Die Deutsche' (referring to a female)

I was confused because I knew it is 'Der Deutsche' and considering that referred to a female I thought that it should be something like 'Die Deutschin'. So I checked and it seems that it is both 'Der/Die Deutsche'. I checked all other countries I know and it seems that this is unique even citizens of Saxony are 'Der Sachse' and 'Die Sächsin'

Is there any other case where the male and female citizen is the same, if so, is there a rule to determine?

Comment: I think the answer will dwell on the fact that adjectives usually have the same ending for m and f: der/die blaue, der/die grüne, der/die rote, der/die haarige, der/die vergessene. If you interpret "der/die Deutsche" as substantivized adjective, you would have an explanation. Although it is "der Engländer/die Engländerin", it is still "der/die/das englische". But I am not knowledgeable enough about German morphology to write an actual answer.

Comment: @CarstenS I edited it to be more specific.

Comment: Note that it is (AFAIK): "der Deutsche" but "ein Deutscher". The female equivalent is "die Deutsche" and "eine Deutsche".

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Ich stimme dir zu - *der/die Deutsche* ist vergleichbar mit *der/die Amische*; beides seltene Fälle, in denen kein eigenständiges Substantiv zur Bezeichnung der Gruppenangehörigen verwendet wird.

Comment: welsch/Welscher/Welsche is similar to deutsch/Deutscher/Deutsche

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### der Deutsche, die Deutsche

- Country: Deutschland
- Adjective: deutsch

This is an exception, because the adjective *»deutsch«* does not end with *»-isch«*, whereas all other adjectives that derive from country names do end in *»-isch«*.

But there are also two other exceptions, even when the adjectives do end in *»-isch«*:

---

### der Israeli, die Israeli

- Country: Israel
- Adjective: israelisch

But there also is a second feminine form: *die Israelin*. In official documents you always use *die Israeli*, but in common speech you will more often hear *die Israelin*.

Sorry, I can't explain why here the ending of the noun is *-i*. I guess that there is a latin root, but I have no evidence for this.

---

### der Swasi, die Swasi

- Country: Swasiland
- Adjective: swasiländisch

This name is derived from *Swazi*, which is the name of an ethnic group.

Comment: Burkina Faso, St. Kitts and Nevis, Trinidad and Tobago, …

Comment: @LangLangC: What do you want to say with this list? Please write whole sentences (with subject, verb and all other parts of speech that are needed to form a statement)

Comment: Just a few examples of country-names useful as additions to your first point of "all others". No adjectives in *-isch* for those? Still all exceptional, though. Maybe even more: der Xhosa/dieXhosa?

Comment: The -i of "Israeli" is Hebrew, not Latin.

Answer (score 1):

Mir fällt spontan auch kein anderer "Einwohner"-Begriff ein, der diesem Muster folgt.

*(ein) Deutscher* ist eine lexikalisierte und teilidiomatisierte Substantivierung von *deutsch* (deadjektivisches Substantiv). Grundsätzlich kann sich die Deadjektivierung in unterschiedlichen Graden manifestieren. *(ein) Deutscher* hat keine morphologische Konversion vollzogen, anders als beispielsweise *Invalide*, vgl.: *Er ist ein Invalid**e***, in Abweichung zum adjektivischen Verhalten: *Zum diesjährigen Dschungelcamp treten an, wie jedes Jahr: ein Schöner, ein Hässlicher und ein Invalid**er**.* Bei *Invalide* wird entsprechend auch, wie für Substantive typisch, die feminine Form mit *-in*-Endung markiert: *die Invalidin.* Bei *(ein) Deutscher* wird das adjektivische Flexionsmuster hingegen beibehalten. Deswegen sind aber im Nominativ nach bestimmtem Artikel auch die maskuline und die feminine Form ident; so entspricht es der schwachen Adjektivflexion. Entsprechend auch etwa *(ein) Grüner* - *der/die Grüne* - oder *(ein) Geliebter* - *der/die Geliebte*.

Ich denke, dass diese Art der Wortbildung bei Einwohnerbezeichnungen unüblich ist, weil man typischerweise nicht von einem Adjektiv ableitet, sondern naheliegenderweise vom (substantivischen) Eigennamen des Landes/Ortes ausgeht. Wenn man aus dieser Richtung kommt, gibt es keinen Grund, in die Adjektivflexion zu wechseln. Das abweichende Verhalten von *(ein) Deutscher* mag damit zusammenhängen, dass es sich hier historisch aus einem Adjektiv etabliert hat. Das Adjektiv *deutsch*  gab es schließlich auch schon Jahrhunderte bevor sich langsam ein entsprechender Ländername *(Deutschland)* etabliert hat.

Comment: Generell sollte man Antworten immer in derselben Sprache verfassen, in der die Frage gestellt wurde. Möglicherweise spricht der Fragesteller nicht ausreichend Deutsch um deine Antwort zu verstehen.